# HTTP signature - HMAC-SHA256

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, webhooks, hmacsha256, http-signature

I receive [an incoming transfer event webhook](https://docs.manager.one/#incoming-transfer-event) from the [Manager One API](https://docs.manager.one/#general-information). For signature verification, they employ an [HMAC-SHA256 algorithm](https://docs.manager.one/#documentation-api-signature-verification). They provided me with a shared secret key, which is a combination of numbers and letters that I have placed in my ENV["MANAGER_ONE_SECRET_SIGNATURE"]. For this example, let's assume the value is "shared_secret_key." I have been working on matching the key obtained from the request header information with this shared secret key to successfully verify the webhook.

Here's what I have accomplished thus far:

```
class Api::ManagerOneController < Api::ApplicationController
  def create
    if expected_signature == provided_signature_base64
      request_body = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)["incoming_bank_operation"]
      ManagerOne::Webhooks::IncomingTransferJob.perform_later(request_body)
      render status: :ok, json: { message: "Signature verified successfully" }
    else
      render status: :unauthorized, json: { error: "Unauthorized" }
    end
  end

  private

  def expected_signature
    Base64.strict_encode64(
      OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
        OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha256"),
        ENV["MANAGER_ONE_SECRET_SIGNATURE"],
        signature_input
      )
    )
  end

  def signature_input
    content_length = "\"content-length\": #{request.headers['Content-Length']}\n"
    user_agent = "\"user-agent\": #{request.headers['User-agent']}\n"
    content_type= "\"content-type\": #{request.headers['Content-Type']}\n"
    host = "\"host\": #{request.headers['Host']}\n"
    request_target = "\"(request-target)\": #{"post #{request.path}"}\n"
    date = "\"date\": #{request.headers['Date']}\n"
    digest = "\"digest\": #{request.headers['Digest']}\n"
    signature_params = "\"@signature-params\": (\"content-length\" \"user-agent\" \"content-type\" \"host\" \"(request-target)\" \"date\" \"digest\"); keyid=\"#{ENV["MANAGER_ONE_SECRET_SIGNATURE"]}\"; algorithm=\"hmac-sha256\";"

    "#{content_length}#{user_agent}#{content_type}#{host}#{request_target}#{date}#{digest}#{signature_params}"
  end

  def provided_signature_base64
    request.headers['Signature'].match(/signature="([^"]+)"/)[1]
  end
end
```

The headers change with each request; the data I provided is just an example:

```
expected_signature = "1zmbBUVFEsqlj8G0h8SPdikbu7et4boR/r/HHoLkr2o="
```

I generated the signature_input by following the instructions provided [in this documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-message-signatures-03#section-3.2):

```
signature_input = "\"content-length\": 1107\n\"user-agent\": manager.one\n\"content-type\": application/json\n\"host\": localhost:3000\n\"(request-target)\": post /api/manager_one/webhooks\n\"date\": Mon, 30 Oct 2023 13:02:55 GMT\n\"digest\": SHA-256=sTz9SzsDH3WGcbYSZb+G8Xk1javIUxE0egQaKD1Wyws=\n\"@signature-params\": (\"content-length\" \"user-agent\" \"content-type\" \"host\" \"(request-target)\" \"date\" \"digest\"); keyid=\"shared_secret_key\"; algorithm=\"hmac-sha256\";"
```

The key I'm supposed to match with the expected signature is the one I obtained from the Manager One API documentation example, although it changes with each request:

```
provided_signature_base64 = "pkLgUJmM5FixErazNavlwWizmDZdTDBcMZb9xY3ZUv8="
```

Am I missing something? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out; my signature input had several issues:

- the API documentation lacked instructions on how to create the correct signature input
- since I was using Ngrok, the host I received was "localhost:8000," but I should have used the Ngrok URL instead.
- I was hashing the data in the wrong manner to match the expected signature

In the end, I resolved these issues and arrived at the correct solution:

```
class Api::ManagerOneController < Api::ApplicationController
  def create
    success = expected_signature == provided_signature_base64
    request_body = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)["incoming_bank_operation"]
    ManagerOne::Webhooks::IncomingTransferJob.perform_later(request_body, success)
    render status: :ok, json: { success: true, message: success ? "Authorized" : "Unauthorized" }
  end

  private

  def expected_signature
    hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest("SHA-256", ENV["MANAGER_ONE_SECRET_SIGNATURE"], signature_input)
    Base64.encode64(hmac).chomp
  end

  def signature_input
    content_length = "content-length: #{request.headers['Content-Length']}"
    user_agent = "user-agent: #{request.headers['User-agent']}"
    content_type= "content-type: #{request.headers['Content-Type']}"
    # When using Ngrok in development environment, host must be ngrok url & not localhost:3000
    host = "host: #{request.headers['Host']}"
    request_target = "(request-target): #{"post #{request.path}"}"
    date = "date: #{request.headers['Date']}"
    digest = "digest: #{request.headers['Digest']}"

    "#{content_length}\n#{user_agent}\n#{content_type}\n#{host}\n#{request_target}\n#{date}\n#{digest}"
  end

  def provided_signature_base64
    request.headers['Signature'].match(/signature="([^"]+)"/)[1]
  end
end
```